# How to cast class Type of variable in to an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, casting, angular-services, angular-observable

I have a config class like this.

```
export class Settings {
  values: string[] = ['NAME', 'AGE', 'NIC', 'CITY_LIST'];
  defaultPrice: number = 1
}
```

This is the service class where i am using it.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import {Settings} from '../configurations/settings';

    getConfigs(): Observable <Settings> {
        const configs = new Settings();
        return Observable.of<Settings>(configs);
      }
```

But in here `return Observable.of<Settings>(configs);` shows an error like

**Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.** How can i return this value in this method?

Comment: I think you can just do `return of(configs)` and get the typing.

Comment: I usually see `of` get imported like this: `import { of } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: yes.It's the way